# Is it possible to react to user cancellations of android notifications?

Tags: android, notifications

I have a background service setting up a notification in Android's status bar. The background service is doing some work, but needs to stop when the user **clicks on or cancels** the notification.

I am able to stop the service, if the user **clicks** on the notification by passing an intent to the notification when creating it.

Is it possible to react if the user **cancels** the notification? Or if all notifications are canceled? If so, how?

NB: I define cancel as removing the notification by swiping to the right on it, or clicking on the `x` at the top right to remove all the notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `deleteIntent` of the `Notification`:

> The intent to execute when the status entry is deleted by the user with the "Clear All Notifications" button.